# Get all Windows Kernel object and Security rights of it

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, kernel

I need to get list of access rights to all Win-Kernel objects;
What I do:

```
for (int i=0; i<9999; i++)
    GetKernelObjectSecurity( i, ... ) //result in security_descriptor
    GetSecurityDescriptorDacl( security_descriptor, ... ) // result in lpbDaclPresent
    if (lpbDaclPresent)
        //lpbDaclPresent - need to get
```

> If DACL = Null -> "all can do all"
>
> If DACL != Null -> parsing DACL-mask

---

I'm on the right track ?
By the way, I have:

~300 handles without DACL

~100 handles with DACL
(testing on Windows 7)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve where you think enumerating all the kernel handles is the solution? Manipulating handles you do not own is a sure way to make some other code crash.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bruteforce through the HANDLES don't stop at 9999. Go through all 32bit values.

Alternatively you can enumerate all Usermode-Process-Handles:
http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html

The advantage of this method is, that you know the Handles original Process to use DuplicateHandle if needed.